# How to split directory of big size using linux command

Tags: linux, shell

I am trying to split huge directory of 17 GB into multiple directories of small size. Since I do not found any such command I am trying to do it using a shell script, but it is very slow, I would request you to suggest me the way hpw could I enhance the performance of this script. I also tried to use dirsplit but not able to get example which I could understand:

```
for (( i=0; i <=200000; i++));
do
tt=`find /home/sd/mail/.catans@mail_in/cur/ -type f|head -1 |awk -F '/' '{print $7}'`
   mv /home/sd/mail/.catans@mail_in/cur/$tt /home/sd/mail/.catans@mail_in/bounceSplit/b_1/
done
```

Comment: You're running 200.000 find commands, and then take one result each time. How would this NOT be slow? I'm not understanding exactly what you're trying to achieve, but I'll bet part of the solution is to run `find` **once**.

Comment: On what criteria do you want to partition your files?

Answer (score 1):

Hi while trying to find the solution I tried a command:

```
 time find /home/sd/mail/.cat__ans@mail_in/cur/ -type f|head -30000 | xargs -I '{}' mv '{}' /home/sd/mail/.cat__ans@mail_in/bounceSplit/b_4/
```

Below is the time taken in execution of same:
real    1m32.380s
user    0m11.546s
sys     0m30.394s